# Can we get the "No AI" banner enabled?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-review

The SE network has done some testing on a "No AI content allowed" banner and [has made it available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera?cb=1) for sites that request it.

We've had quite a number of AI generated answers here lately and I think this *might* slightly reduce the number that we see in the future. It certainly won't make it worse.

Each site has to request it, so I'm proposing that we do so.

I guess that an Up Vote on the question indicates agreement that we should move that way? (I dunno - there really isn't a poll option here...)

Comment: I don't understand the whole thing. If it's *correct* then why does it matter. It's the humans clicking on the arrows that are the problem. But seeing as there's no solution for that, then yes(?), assuming AI answers are total crap. Would we ignore an AI script that auto closed dupes? Kinda hard to drive ad traffic if this is just all computers doing SE the way it's supposed to be done. 10 years-in *there are no new questions*. - That happened at like year 3. We just keep turning over users who know that and/or care.

Comment: Will the banner help? Probably only a little, because the people actually posting the AI junk probably don't care much. But hopefully the banner will discourage some otherwise well-meaning "hey, I found a ChatGPT answer to this question!" people. Now if an answer deleted because AI *despite* the banner could trigger an automatic long-term ban of the user then we might be on to something...

Comment: @Mazura - this has been debated to beyond blue-in-the-face on the more 'computer-oriented' stacks & main meta. Amongst the troubles with AI 1) It doesn't check its answers & makes things up with equal authority as accepted fact [google 'AI hallucinations']. 2) it is plagiarised from uncredited sources.

Comment: The use of AI, @Mazura, eliminates the need to think. Either on the part of the person posting it (copy question, paste into AI random generator, copy result, paste into answer), or on the part of the reader (the computer says it's true, so it must be true). People have a hard enough time thinking for themselves as it is, I'm against encouraging _less_ thinking.

Comment: Experiments were done in the 80s. Kids were given calculators and allowed to use them for math tests. Some gave correct answers, some gave answers that were off by 10%, some off by 50% (numbers approximate - I don't remember the exact details). Kids just wrote down the answer the calculator gave them, even when it was blatantly wrong, like `5 x 10 = 55`. The math questions were appropriate for the age group and were simple enough that the kids _should_ have been able to do them in their head and _known_ that the calculator was wrong. It's not like they were asking 6 year olds to do calculus.

Comment: I suggest some extra points - "No AI questions, No AI comments, no AI voting"  Because making it clear seems wise

Comment: I'm with you 100%, @Criggie. Can we get SE to modify the message for us? :D

Comment: @Criggie -  I think you may have to raise a separate request This one as it stands has been flagged to staff as our intent to proceed, by being tagged 'status-review' by a mod. I presume when done, it will be re-tagged by staff as 'status-complete'. Right now there are only two minor variations on offer & I never considered the 2nd option to be appropriate, so I very much assume we'll get the main one. Bear in mind, this will appear when someone tries to answer, so it won't necessarily be the appropriate place to mention comments or votes.

Comment: Having no idea whatsoever how the [tag:status-review] process works or what kind of time frame there might be, could someone please explain and/or give an update on where this is in that process? Will we be notified if this is approved or denied?

Comment: Update from SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396626/163027

Comment: I've also listed this post here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384922/163027

Comment: Great updates, @BMitch. Is there any expected timeline for getting the banner posted here? I would presume that _everyone_ will see it at least once, so we'll know once it's in place, I'm just curious on whenish.

Comment: @FreeMan they have a [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/163027) describing the process and their historical response rate, but not a lot of detail on the timeline. Running the SEDE query with the last 3 months in the range, I see a lot of sites asking for the banner and none are marked as completed yet.

Answer (score 14):

*I'm just going to copy/paste my answer from [Super User's Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15129/should-we-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-our-policy-on-ai-generated-content) on the same topic…*

## Yes.

It can't hurt. It costs us nothing. People will either read it & pay attention or not, but if only 1% read it & then don't post the AI answer they were about to, then the banner has been successful, even if just to a small degree.

Even for those well-versed in site etiquette, you'll only see it once, so the annoyance factor is low.

Comment: Agree. Human answers are on-brand for StackExchange. Announcing that with zero ambiguity for answer _consumers_ is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we really need this alternative answer, but let's see.
As noted by FreeMan in the OP, Meta doesn't have a true poll structure other than for Moderator Elections, so the accepted method is to provide two opposing answers to a binary decision & count those up/downvotes. (& as mentioned in comments, downvotes don't do my rep any good, so I'm hoping people will just upvote their preferred answer & ignore the other ;)

This separates votes on agreeing/liking or disagreeing/disliking the question itself to just votes supporting each argument [as meta is not the same as main, a downvoted question may or may not indicate a bad question but a disagreement of the sentiment it proposes].

## No.

We don't need this.
*[Supply your own reasoning if necessary.]*

Comment: You may want to make this a community answer so the down votes don't hit your personal score. OTOH, you may not care (I mean, how many rainbows and unicorns does a guy need) but I thought I mention it.

Comment: I hadn't considered that, tbh, but if I make one CW, then I ought to make *both* CW. Now I'm well past 10k on here, I'm no longer worried about the odd downvote here & there. I could hope people will only upvote their preferred answer rather than downvote the other. We'll see  ;))

Comment: I was gonna down vote this one (just to offset any crazy people :D), but you seem nice enough, I didn't want to give you a bad rep. ;) But, fair point, I won't vote on this one at all...

Comment: @FreeMan Meta doesn't have actual rep so no votes here affect your main site rep